# Shuffling the first name and surname of authors in latex

Tags: bibtex, elsarticle

I want to have my references as first and middle name initials and, surname. Instead, I am getting the opposite. My bibtex (`.bib`) library is ref and `.bst` is `model4-names` provided by Elsevier. is The code in my `.tex` file for the Elsevier journal is as follows.

```
\documentclass[preprint,review,10pt]{elsarticle}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{3cm}}
\usepackage{algorithmicx}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{algpseudocode}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{algorithm,algpseudocode}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\newboolean{somevariable}
\setboolean{somevariable}{false} 
\begin{document}

\begin{frontmatter}

\title{paper title}
\begin{abstract}
....
...
...
...
\bibliography{ref}
\bibliographystyle{model4-names}
\end{document}
```

`model4-names.bst` enable me to get sorted references but not in the format of the journal. The above code generates references in the following style

> [1] **Asghar, M.N., Ghanbari, M..** An efficient security system for cabac binstrings of h. 264/svc. Circuits and Systems for Video Technology, IEEE Transactions on **2013**;23(3):425–437.

and the journal expect it in the following style

> [1] M.N. Asghar, M. Ghanbari, An efficient security system for cabac binstrings of h. 264/svc. , IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems for Video Technology 23(3) (2013) 425–437.

**Three things** are missing as highlighted by bold.

1. Order of first name and surname, and
2. Parenthesis around year field for journal but not for conferences.
3. Also, there should be a comma instead of double dots (..) after the last author's name.

May I know if I am missing anything?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Are you using `model4-names` because the author instructions about the submission say so? In this case, leave the choice to the bib style.

Comment: I am using model4-names.bst provided by Elsevier to support alphabetical order of references. I am playing with this bst since a while and has been able to get references in the required style, however, there is a comma after the first name (initial) of each author.

Comment: Apparently Elsevier likes it.

Comment: @user110667 That's the style choice of Elsevier (amongst others)

Answer (score 1):

For this case, download and place the  `elsarticle-num` bibliography style (.bst) files in your working directory. It is perfectly working. Moreover, for your reference, I am attaching the screenshot. Yes, you can sort the references using `\biboptions{sort&compress}`. You just need to add this options before the `\begin{document}` environment. Hope it helps. Moreover, you can also try the other available biboptions.

```
round  -  round parentheses are used (default)
square -  square brackets are used   [option]
curly  -  curly braces are used      {option}
angle  -  angle brackets are used    <option>
semicolon  -  multiple citations separated by semi-colon
colon  - same as semicolon, an earlier confusion
comma  -  separated by comma
numbers-  selects numerical citations
super  -  numerical citations as superscripts
sort   -  sorts multiple citations according to order in ref. list
sort&compress   -  like sort, but also compresses numerical citations
compress - compresses without sorting
```

[image]

```
\bibliographystyle{elsarticle-num}
\bibliography{bib}
```

Comment: Bibliographic style elsarticle-num.bst allows to obtain the references in exactly similar style but now they are not sorted. How can i sort them alphabatically (according to authors surname) using elsearticle-num.bst file?

Comment: @user110667. The above mentioned answer is now been edited. Hope it suffice your need.